# Some real analysis problem. Can you tell if this proof is alright?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> a) If $f:\mathbb{I}\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c|x-y|^{\alpha}\ \ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{I},\ \alpha>1.$$
> Then $f$ is a  constant  function.
>
> b) If $g$ is an antiderivative of $f$ in $[0,1]$, such that $g'(t)=f(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, also $f(t)<1$ for all $t\in(0,1)$. Then
> $$g(t)-g(0)<t\ \forall t\in(0,1].$$

Proof a)

For any $x,y\in\mathbb{I}$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq 0$, so
$$0\leq \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq c|x-y|^{\alpha - 1}\\ \lim_{x\rightarrow y}\ 0\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow y}c|x-y|^{\alpha - 1},$$
since
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\ 0=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow y}c|x-y|^{\alpha - 1}$$
Then, follows by the squeeze theorem that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=0.$$

Therefore $|f|$ is differentiable and continuous for all $x,y\in\mathbb{I}$. Furthermore, $|f'(y)|=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{I}$. Invoking the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists \xi\in(x,y)\subset\mathbb{I}$, with $x\neq y$, such that
$$\ \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|=|f'(\xi)|=0$$
implying
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=0 \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y).$$
Therefore $f$ is constant.

Proof b)

Since $g(t)$ is the antiderivative for $f(t)$ in $[0,1],$ follows from the Mean Value Theorem for $t\neq 0$ and by hypothesis that
$$\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}=g'(\xi)<1,\ \xi\in(0,t)$$
and therefor
$$g(t)-g(0)<t,\ t\in(0,1].$$

---

Note: I posted this a week ago and since then I've made some changes that I were told to do. Now I just want to make sure everything it's ok.

Comment: In a), you find that $|f|$ is differentiable but the argument actually shows that $f$ is differentiable because $x=0 \iff |x|=0$.

Comment: a) It's not $|f|$ that is differentiable, but $f$, and the limit is indeed $0$. However, no need to use mean value theorem. If $\lim_{x\to y}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|=0$ for all $y$, then $f'(y)=0$ for all $y$.

Comment: b) Why mean value theorem ? You have that $g(t)=g(0)+\int_0^t f(s)\,\mathrm d s<t$ because $f<1$...